# Android app for phone on tablet

Tags: android-manifest, android, android-resolution, android-market-filtering

What is the best approach for developer, who published an application for the phone device, which looks nice up to 480x800px, but is extremely ugly on big tablet screens (800x1280px).

- First option is to manually remove device by device from android market list (but there is about 819 devices)
- Second is setting android:maxSdkVersion in manifest - this will exclude all 3.x devices which are tablets only, but there will remain 2.x tablets + it will not run on 4.x devices
- Last option is to check the version and resolution on the application start-up

Any tips? You can of course argue that we should make it compatible with the tablets, but it is considerable effort we cannot spend on this.

Regards,
STeN

Comment: If you only want it used on certain resolutions, check the resolution on app startup (install?) and display a message that it's not compatible if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Google addresses this in the SDK documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html